# Missing string after space erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have used html.erb template in Rails to passing some value for HTML input and my source code looks like this:

```
   <% all = "All value" %>
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=<%= all %>>
```

But when the view is rendered, it seems like a string after space was missing and I just got:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="All">
```

But my expection is:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="All value">
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You're not quoting it, so normal HTML parsing rules apply.

Comment: You can also just use the [Rails helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) instead of slumming it `<%= text_field_tag(:name, all) %>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your all variable like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<%= all %>">
```

Comment: ... It is already a string. There's no "or"--property values must be quoted if there's anything that will have HTML parsing applied.